# get live text field data using jquery

Tags: jquery, jqueryform

I want to get data that user enter in the text field with name and id `Name`, which has a similar structure like below;

```
<form id="testform" name="testform" method="post" action="process.php">
    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">Name</td>
            <td id="Name" class="style2">
                <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I want to store the data in a variable.

How can i make this possible?

Thanks in advance... `:)`

blasteralfred

Comment: Did you even try looking at the jQuery API docs?

Comment: You should not use the same id twice even on different elements.

Comment: You cannot have 2 elements with the same `id`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var nameValue = "";
$("input[id=Name]").change(function(){
  nameValue = $(this).val();
});
```

If you can remove the id="Name" for the td (table cell) element, you can try the code given below and this will be faster compared to the previous version

```
var nameValue = "";
$("#Name").change(function(){
  nameValue = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var contents = $("#Name").val();
```

Of course as `a'r` very correctly points out (I missed that), you need to have the `Name` id only on *one* element -- the text box. There's no reason to give it to the `<td>` anyway.

Comment: Not fair :( You were faster just because you have chosen longer variable name so your answer got accepted :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = $("#Name").val();
```

Hmm.. too short answer :X